# animate view as serial pages

Tags: android, animation

I have three view on the same place. I need  to show them like they are in a serial page.

[image]

When btn1 pressed view1 need to show. When I change view to view3 the view 1 & 2 two should slide to left so that user thinks these views are serial, as in the pic.

Comment: +1 graphic is a thoughtful touch, worth 1000 words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **ViewFlipper** and **animation** for your requirement. Below link provides how to use ViewFlipper and animation. Understand the code in this example and modify this to your actual layouts and requirements.

[Android transitions- slide in and slide out](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

You can use ViewPager also, but it is some what typical than ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is ViewPager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

In some case may be very helpfull ViewFlipper http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html